# SystemD error on tyring to add docker container

Tags: docker, puppet

I am having a go with the [puppetlabs docker module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker).

I've added the following code to my puppetmaster as a test case:

```
  docker::run { 'helloworld':
    image   => 'base',
    command => '/bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"',
  }
```

on my puppet clients, I'm running the Amazon Linux AMI's. When doing a puppet run, I am receiving the following error:

> Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Base/Docker::Run[helloworld]/Service[docker-helloworld]:
>   Provider systemd is not functional on this host

Which makes sense, the Amazon Linux does not have Systemd. What is the correct way to resolve this? Is there a way to make the docker module work without systemd?

Comment: Was this answer below correct @thomasvdberge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Docker module you're using actually supports Amazon Linux, if you have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-docker/blob/1896eca89c7160c371c6e949205102569c6b0931/manifests/params.pp#L177-L223).

On Amazon Linux 1,

```
# facter osfamily 
RedHat
```

So, the assumption there is that all of the Redhat linux OS family uses Systemd.

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/893110/374465) answer, you could actually enable Systemd on Amazon Linux. Another option is to use Amazon Linux 2.

Failing that, you would need to patch in explicit support for Amazon Linux 1 in the Docker module. It's probably not hard to do. You may find you can make a minor change to that params.pp file and send in a PR upstream, or fork it locally if you prefer.

Comment: Updated the AMIS to use Amazon Linux 2, which does use systemd. (And since Amazon Linux 1 was going end of life anyway, it was a nice bonus)

Comment: Thanks. Updated in light of your info.